# Oracle find dates same day different months

Tags: oracle, function, date, loops, range

i have a question,  i would like to find all the records from a table that match the day and the year of a given date, in all the months, for example

Given the date (mm/dd/yyyy) :

```
'12/24/2010'
```

Return all the records with the dates:

```
'12/24/2010'
'11/24/2010'
'10/24/2010'
'09/24/2010'
'08/24/2010'
'07/24/2010'
'06/24/2010'
'05/24/2010'
'04/24/2010'
'03/24/2010'
'02/24/2010'
'01/24/2010'
```

Is there a way to do it in a single query?
I would like to implement it in a function, but wouldn't like to use a loop (just for speed).
Any help would be deeply appreciated!! :)

Comment: What is type of field with dates? `DATE` or `VARCHAR2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your columns are all defined as `DATE`, functionally, you could certainly do something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
 WHERE to_char( date_column, 'DD-YYYY' ) = to_char( date '2010-12-24', 'DD-YYYY' )
```

You could potentially create a function-based index on `to_char( date_column, 'DD-YYYY' )` to make the query more efficient.

Comment: it works like a charm!! thanks, now i would ask, i found this way to do it:

select * from table where 
to_char(date_column,'yyyy/mm/dd') like '2010/%/24';

which would perform best with a lot of records?

Comment: @E.Diaz - Assuming that you create a function-based index on the `date_column` expression and that both queries used the index, I would expect performance to be pretty similar.  But the equality predicate that I posted would generally make it easier on the optimizer to get the cardinality estimates right in order to generate the best plan.  The `LIKE` probably requires a bit more CPU but if you're talking about large amounts of data, I/O should be the bottleneck so the CPU difference is less important.

Comment: Not fast! If the data is very big, is it very slow??

Comment: @Gank If you have a lot of data, you would definitely want to create the function based index

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
SELECT date_column FROM some_table 
WHERE 
TO_DATE(date_column, 'MM') = TO_DATE(given_date, 'MM') 
AND 
TO_DATE(date_column, 'YYYY')) = TO_DATE(given_date, 'YYYY')
```

given_date is your '12/24/2010'.

Comment: tried it, it gives me the ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
error... :(

Comment: You can't call `to_date` on a `DATE`.  Well, you can.  It just forces Oracle to implicitly cast the `DATE` to a `VARCHAR2` first using the session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.  But whatever you've set your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to, one or both of the `TO_DATE` calls will fail because the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` cannot be simultaneously `MM` and `YYYY`.  And setting the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to either of these values would have a very high risk of causing other issues.

Comment: Try `select date_column from some_table 
where 
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(some_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM') =  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(given_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM') 
AND
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(some_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'YYYY') =  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(given_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'YYYY')`